# Адаптивные таблицы на CSS

Tags: css

Появилась необходимость в табличном представлении части информации на сайте.

Частично решила задачу адаптивности таблицы по найденному в сети примеру. Решение - в перестраивании представления данных в строчный режим (при медиа `min-width = 980` и меньше столбцы "укладываются" горизонтально). Но до этого момента таблица в своем обычном табличном представлении никак не "ужимается", вылезая в итоге за пределы дива по ширине (в предыдущих версиях *html* таких проблем не было, таблицы "адаптировались" автоматически).

Сейчас у меня отлично адаптируется пустая таблица. Но при внесении в нее данных на разрешениях от `980рх` и выше **таблица растягивает div**, в котором находится **по горизонтали**, вместо того, чтобы самой "ужиматься". 
Внизу появляется полоса прокрутки.

Подскажите, как решить проблему. Желательно без *javascript*.

Пример:

```css
.responstable {
  margin: 1em 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #024457;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #167F92;
  text-align: center;
}
.responstable tr {
  border: 1px solid #D9E4E6;
}
.responstable tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #EAF3F3;
}
.responstable th {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #D9E4E6;
  background-color: #cecece;
  color: #000000;
  padding: .5em;
  font-size: .8em;
}
.responstable th:first-child {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}
.responstable th:nth-child(2) {
  display: table-cell;
}
.responstable th:nth-child(2) span {
  display: none;
}
.responstable th:nth-child(2):after {
  content: attr(data-th);
}
@media (min-width: 980px) {
  .responstable th:nth-child(2) span {
    display: block;
  }
  .responstable th:nth-child(2):after {
    display: none;
  }
}
.responstable td {
  display: inline;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  max-width: 7em;
}
.responstable td:first-child {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid #D9E4E6;
}
@media (min-width: 980px) {
  .responstable td {
    border: 1px solid #D9E4E6;
  }
}
.responstable th,
.responstable td {
  text-align: center;
  margin: .5em 1em;
}
@media (min-width: 980px) {
  .responstable th,
  .responstable td {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 1em;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="responstable">
  <tr>

    <th data-th="Характеристики"><span>Кол-во<br /> комнат</span>
    </th>
    <th>Адрес, р-н</th>
    <th>Метро</th>
    <th>S
      <br />
      <br />о
      <br />б
      <br />щ</th>
    <th>S
      <br />
      <br />к
      <br />о
      <br />м
      <br />н</th>
    <th>S
      <br />
      <br />к
      <br />у
      <br />х</th>
    <th>Эт</th>
    <th>С/у</th>
    <th>Тип дома</th>
    <th>Цена</th>
    <th>Срок</th>
    <th>Примечания</th>
    <th>TV</th>
    <th>Хол</th>
    <th>СтМ</th>
    <th>Тел</th>
    <th>Инт</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2к.кв.</td>
    <td>ул.Софьи Ковалевской, д.5, корп.5, Калининский р-н</td>
    <td>Академич, 10 мин.пешком</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>(18+12)</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>4/7</td>
    <td>разд с/у</td>
    <td>пан</td>
    <td>18.000</td>
    <td>11мес</td>
    <td>Меб+</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1к.кв.</td>
    <td>Гражданский пр-кт, д.19, корп.3, Калининский р-н</td>
    <td>Академическая, 7 м.п.</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>5/9</td>
    <td>совм с/у</td>
    <td>Кирп</td>
    <td>16.000</td>
    <td>12мес</td>
    <td>Только Кух/Меб, +КУ, +Свет, Залог 50 %, Чисто, Хор/Сост, Без/Меб, Кух/Меб, Окна-Двор, Окна-Зелень, Ванна Сидячая, Газ/Плита, Не Рассм Гастарб/Рабоч/Строит, Гражд/РФ, Для 1-3 Чел &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1к.кв.</td>
    <td>Невский р-н, Товарищеский пр-кт, д.16, корп.1</td>
    <td>Большевиков пр., 12 м.п.</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>3/16</td>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>19.000</td>
    <td>11мес</td>
    <td>Меб+ &nbsp;Хор/Сост, Есть Все Необх Оборуд/Мебель!, Спальн/Мест-3, Для Гражд/РФ, +КУ, Залог &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>+</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2к.кв.</td>
    <td>Фрунзенский р-н, ул.Белградская, д.28, корп.5</td>
    <td>Международная, 15 м.п.</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>14+16</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>1/12</td>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td>ПН</td>
    <td>20.000</td>
    <td>11мес</td>
    <td>Меб+&nbsp; +КУ, Залог/Вн/Част/Поэт, Гражд/РФ, Для 1-3 Чел, Для Сем/Пары с Реб &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>+</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2к.кв.</td>
    <td>Красносельский р-н, ул.Маршала Казакова, д.50, корп.1</td>
    <td>Автово, Ленинский пр., пр.Ветеранов, 15 м.тр.</td>
    <td>?</td>
    <td>15+16</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>8/10</td>
    <td>разд с/у</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>23.000</td>
    <td>11мес</td>
    <td>Лдж, Новый Дом, Нов/Дом, Отл/Сост, Стекло-Пакеты, С/У в Кафеле, Застекл/ЛДЖ, Встр/Кух, Сдается с 11.05, а Смотреть Мож/Сейчас! &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>+</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1к.кв.</td>
    <td>Московский р-н, ул.Ленсовета, д.51</td>
    <td>Звездная, Московская, 10 м.п.</td>
    <td>42</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>3/12</td>
    <td>совм с/у</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>21.000</td>
    <td>11мес</td>
    <td>Меб+ , Блк, Евро/Рем, Есть вся Быт/Тех, Есть Все Необх Оборуд, Развитая Инфра/Стр-ра, Гражд/РФ, +КУ &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>+</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1к.кв.</td>
    <td>Московский р-н, Витебский пр-кт, д.31</td>
    <td>Парк Победы, 4 ост.</td>
    <td>33</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>2/5</td>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>17.000</td>
    <td>11мес</td>
    <td>Хор/Сост, Есть Все Необх Оборуд/Мебель!, Для Гражд/РФ, +КУ, Залог &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>+</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2к.кв.</td>
    <td>Выборгский р-н,ул.Сикейроса, д.1</td>
    <td>Озерки 330&nbsp;м, 5 м.п.</td>
    <td>91</td>
    <td>24+22</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>7/9</td>
    <td>совм с/у</td>
    <td>Кирп</td>
    <td>40.000</td>
    <td>11мес</td>
    <td>Лдж, Есть Лифт, Без/Жив, Для 1-2 Чел, Для Пары, Идеальн/Сост, Чистая Парадная, Дизайн, Евро/Рем, Есть Все Необх Оборуд/Мебель!, Развитая Инфра/Стр-ра, Озеро, +КУ &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>+</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2к.кв.</td>
    <td>Пушкинский р-н, п.Шушары, тер.Ленсоветовский, д.288</td>
    <td>Купчино 9.4&nbsp;км, Звездная 10.6&nbsp;км, Московская 13&nbsp;км</td>
    <td>55</td>
    <td>13+16</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>5/5</td>
    <td>разд с/у</td>
    <td>Кирп
      <br />/Мон</td>
    <td>19.000</td>
    <td>12мес</td>
    <td>Возм с Меб, 2Блк, Новый Дом</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>-</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Пример на стороннем редакторе: [jsfiddle-bL4u90x4](http://jsfiddle.net/bL4u90x4/)

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, пишите вопросы более кратко, конкретнее и яснее со вставкой вашего кода, что бы пользователи могли дать конструктивный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас `Padding` в ячейках таблицы размером `1em`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уберите его:

```
.responstable th, .responstable td{
    padding: 1em 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это действительно помогло. Мне 20 минут назад на другом сервисе посоветовали то же самое. Но один вопрос у меня остался. А почему эти внутренние отступы не "берутся" за счет внутреннего пространства ячейки? Почему увеличивается ширина таблицы вместо этого? Мне это кажется несколько нелогичным :(

Comment: @Наталья потому-что уменьшать некуда, самое длинное слово в строке не дает это сделать. Вы же не указали, что хотите разбивать слова (`td{word-break: break-word;}`)

Comment: @Наталья почитайте также о свойстве `box-sizing`.

Comment: Спасибо. Вопрос решен изменением padding с 1 em на 0. И все отлично стало адаптироваться.

Comment: @Наталья Наш сайт отличается от социальных сетей. Он помогает решать прикладные задачи. Поэтому мы используем комментарии только по делу — уточнить проблему, дать конструктивную критику или добавить полезную информацию. Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers